# MFMailComposeViewController bringing up NSException

Tags: iphone, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller, nsexception

I have done a search for this problem, and have not found an answer, which is leading me to write my firs tquestion here.

The problem is when I press the button which calls the metho below, I get an exception on this line: `[self presentModalViewController:mailViewController animated:YES];` and the exception is:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x20f6c'

In addition, I am running my app on the simulator if that helps.

I got the magority of the code from [here](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/49393-sending-plist-attachment.html).

Here is my code (with the email address blanked out):

```
    // set up the email address array
    NSArray *email = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"foo", nil];

    // Set up the view controller
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    // Set up the email to send to
    [mailViewController setSubject:@"foo"];
    [mailViewController setToRecipients:[email objectAtIndex:0]];

    // Get the path to the plist
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];  
    NSString *path = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"foo.plist"];

    // Get the plist from the path
    NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    [mailViewController addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"plist" fileName:@"foo"];

    // Fill out the email body text 
    NSString *emailBody = @"Attached PLIST file";
    [mailViewController setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

    // Release the array
    [email release];

    if (mailViewController != nil) {
        [self presentModalViewController:mailViewController animated:YES];
        [mailViewController release];
    }
```

What appears to be causing the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `setToRecipients` you have to specify an array, not a string. So you could pass your `email`-array.

Comment: This was the problem! Thank you so much for pointing this out for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(IBAction)btnemail:(id)sender{
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

[picker setSubject:@"subject"];
NSString *emailid=btnEmail.titleLabel.text;
NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:emailid];
[picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];

NSString *emailBody = @"";
[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
    [self.parentViewController presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}else {

}
[picker release];
```

}